# How to solve "Setup version for Namespace_Module is not specified issue"

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, installation, ultimo

I have been trying to install ultimo theme and after installation, I am getting this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'Infortis_Infortis' is not specified

Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'Infortis_Infortis' is not specified
#0 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Infortis_Infort...', '2.0.0')
#1 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Infortis_Infort...')
#2 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#5 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#8 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/quitling/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/quitling/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /var/www/html/quitling/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#14 {main}
```

I have checked, module.xml is fine and have tried several references of stackexchange but none of them worked. Database has proper entry of it.

Here is my module.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Infortis_Infortis" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Please help to solve.

Comment: Try:

php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Module_Name  
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: have already tried that @NikunjVadariya but that didn't help

Comment: have you tried? chmod 775 <module path> -R

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach

Comment: @ManishJoy can you post your `module.xml`?

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I have updated, please check

Comment: pls update file as i given in my answer and check again

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I tried nik, but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue many times.

Most of the time it was an issue with module folder/files permissions so make sure you've given proper permission to module for **testing purpose** you can give full permission like following

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/code/yourmodule
```

and run following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Another rare possibility is the wrong syntax in your module XML's so please check all XML are proper.

**EDIT :**

If your module has dependency on other modules then please make sure you've installed all the required modules first.

Comment: I already tried that. not getting any solution of that.

Comment: By giving 777 permission?

Comment: Yes, I tried both 777 as well as 755, didn't got the error resolved

Comment: Can you provide your module for testing purpose to resolve this error?

Comment: well, I found something weird, this issue was occurring on my system only. Worked well on the server as well as other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Infortis_Infortis" setup_version="2.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Try and check again: sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/di

Comment: ok, let me try!

Comment: still getting the error